Https with traefik
I am trying to make a website use https via traefik, but since I added traefik I get a 404 and it is still not https. If I change the view component to expose and use port 80, it does render, but of course it is not https.
note the hostname and IP are correct on the server, assume foo.com is correct.
docker-compose.yml
    version: '3'
services:
    view:
        build:
            context: ./
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.view.rule=Host(`foo.com`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.view.entrypoints=websecure"
            - "traefik.http.routers.view.tls=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.view.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
        networks:
            - traefik
        ports:
            - "8080"
    reverse-proxy:
        image: traefik:v2.11
        command: --configFile=/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
            - ./acme.json:/acme.json
        networks:
            - traefik
    grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana
        container_name: grafana
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        volumes:
            - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        container_name: prometheus
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - 9090:9090
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
            - prom_data:/prometheus
volumes:
    grafana-storage: {}
    prom_data:

networks:
    traefik:
        external: true

trarfik.yml
entryPoints:
    web:
        address: ":80"
    websecure:
        address: ":443"

providers:
    docker:
        exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
    myresolver:
        acme:
            email: mike@tyeman.io
            storage: acme.json
            httpChallenge:
                entryPoint: web

http:
    routers:
        http-catchall:
            rule: "HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)"
            entryPoints:
                - web
            middlewares:
                - redirect-to-https

    middlewares:
        redirect-to-https:
            redirectScheme:
                scheme: https
                permanent: true
        hsts:
            headers:
                -   name: Strict-Transport-Security
                    value: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

I would like all the URLs to be https, but just have the view is also ok. From my end it looks to be correct but I am lacking some experience with traefik.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Hello. It seems that you are redirecting http to https, but traefik is not listening on https. I actually run dockerized traefik and grafana in my server. Are you still looking for an answer by any chance?

@Kikito I. expose 443. "443:443" or are you suggesting something else. Yes I am looking for an answer.

so my suggestion is first removing  - "traefik.http.routers.view.entrypoints=websecure" from view service and let Traefik do http-to-https routing. @Mike3355

ok. @Kikito thanks but it sadly had no effect.

ah.. sorry to hear that. my config kinda looks like this. i thought the problem was allowing your http entrypoint to redirect to https.
